# How can i ignore languages key when search in translated data ? spatie/laravel-translatable

Tags: laravel, laravel-translatable

i have languages table stored in DB when i search for word "en" or "ar" or "fr" it return all data from database without filtration .
how can i ignore languages key when search for text to avoid return all results  ?

screen shoot for languages table

https://prnt.sc/SWkTzULgP5P5

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.